# Get values of all selected Checkboxes using Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Apologies if this **EXACT** question has been asked elsewhere as I've searched over the internet but I've found somewhat similar scenarios and their solutions but not one that I'm in search of. Hoping someone could assist me in this. So here goes,

> I need to obtain the value of all the checkboxes that have been
> checked. The checkboxes are dynamically created based on the number of Array (assets) items

I am creating a form which uses **ngFor** to go through an array, and create checkboxes for each field. So what I've done is something like this,

```html
    <form>
      <div class="row"><label>Assets</label></div>
      <div *ngFor='let asset of assets' [(ngModel)]='assets'>
        <div class="col-8"><input type="checkbox" name="{{asset}}" (change)="onChange()"></div>
        <div class="col-35"><label>{{asset}}</label></div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

There are plenty of solutions outside but unfortunately everyone is coming with an example where the array is more like a Key:Value pair, for instance,

```
    this.someArray = [
       {id:1, name: someName, isSelect: false},
       {id:2, name: someOtherName, isSelect: false}
    ]
```

I understand how to work with such kind of array structure but in my case, I have the following String Array,

```
    assets: String[] = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
```

My question is, how can I get all the values that have been checked when I have just a simple Array of Strings. What I've done uptil now is something like this,
**asset.component.html**

```html
    <form>
    <div class="row"><label>Assets</label></div>
    <div *ngFor='let asset of assets' [(ngModel)]='assets'>
    <div class="col-8"><input type="checkbox" name="{{asset}}" (change)="onChange()"></div>
    <div class="col-35"><label>{{asset}}</label></div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

**asset.component.ts**

```
    export class AppComponent  {
      name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
    
      assets: String[] = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
      
      onChange(): void {
        alert(this.assets);
      }
    }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Looking forward to hearing from you soon,

For references, here is the StackBlitz implementation (Not completed yet) though,

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jtnzhp?file=src/app/app.component.html

Kind Regards

Comment: Are you using Angular Material checkbox or native checkbox input element as in the Stackblitz example?

Comment: I would recommend you to take a look at this https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#creating-dynamic-forms first, you could instead of the button for adding more just do it based on the data you want to add to the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

**HTML file:**

```html
<div *ngFor="let asset of assets">
  <input (change)="onChange(asset)" type="checkbox" value="{{ asset }}" />{{asset}}
</div>
```

**TypeScript file:**

```js
assets: string[] = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
all_selected_values: string[] = [];

onChange(value: string): void {
  if (this.all_selected_values.includes(value)) {
    this.all_selected_values = this.all_selected_values.filter((item) => item !== value);
  } else {
    this.all_selected_values.push(value);
  }
  console.log(this.all_selected_values);
}
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uzfaoh?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Brilliant!!! Didn't realise it was just this simple and amaed that I don't find this info in any of the online tutorials ... all work in a very set way, 2 dimensional arrays and simply use the key, value style working ... But hey, it worked like wonders. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to pass the property name of this.someArray, what you can do is something like this:

```
(change)="onChange(asset.name)"
```